# How does meanshift tracking work? (using histograms)

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, histogram

I know, that the Meanshift-Algorithm calculates the mean of a pixel density and checks, if the center of the roi is equal with this point. If not, it moves the new ROI center to the mean center and checks again... . Like in this picture:

[image]

For density, it is clear how to find the mean point. But it can't simply calculate the mean of a histogram and get the new position by this point. How can this algorithm work using color histogram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature space in your image is 2D.

Say you have an intensity image (so it's 1D) then you would just have a line (e.g. from 0 to 255) on which the points are located. The circles shown above would just be line segments on that [0,255] line. Depending on their means, these line segments would then shift, just like the circles do in 2D.

You talked about color histograms, so I assume you are talking about RGB.
In that case your feature space is 3D, so you have a sphere instead of a line segment or circle. Your axes are R,G,B and pixels from your image are points in that 3D feature space. You then still look where the mean of a sphere is, to then shift the center towards that mean.